# MatBlazor Button Link is not parsed by routing

Tags: url-routing, .net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side, matblazor

I'm using [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/) for my website and I've implemented Google Authentication using this great blog: 
[Google Authentication in Server-Side Blazor](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4356/Google-Authentication-in-Server-Side-Blazor.aspx)

I want a login button (`MatButton`) in my `MatAppBar`.

The original code has a link: `<a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary" href="/Login" target="_top">Login</a>`.
This link works. I'm redirected to my `OnGetAsync` of my `LoginModel`. But it is not matching my UI style.

This button does go to the right page, but my `OnGetAsync` of my `LoginModel` is not triggered and only the default `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.` is shown.
`<MatButton Class="mat" Outlined="true" Icon="Google" Label="Inloggen" Link="/Login"></MatButton>`

I think I need to tweak my routing, but can't find how.

**Update**:
My Login.cshtml.cs:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        string provider = "Google";
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Page("./Login",
            pageHandler: "Callback",
            values: new { returnUrl }),
        };
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, authenticationProperties);
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEmbeddedBlazorContent(typeof(MatBlazor.BaseMatComponent).Assembly);

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue and used the navigationmanager option listed above but had to pass the ForceLoad parameter as "true"

```
 void LoginClick()
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login",true);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks adding `ForceLoad parameter as "true"` did the trick. I've marked your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full URL

```
<MatButton Class="mat" Outlined="true" Icon="Google" Label="Inloggen"
 Link="BaseUrl/Login"></MatButton>
```

or
 using  navigation manager to navigate that page

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationmanager
    <MatButton Class="mat" Outlined="true" Icon="Google" Label="Inloggen" Onclick="@(()=>)"></MatButton>
    code{
void clic()
{
navigationmanager.Navigateto("/Login")
}
}
```

Comment: I tried both, same result: no login. I'll update my post with my login code.